# TypeError: wrapper() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning

I am trying to use an sci-kit learn optimizer but I am having some issues that I can't resolve.I'm trying to use Bayesian optimization to tune my hyperparameters for my LSTM DNN. Any help would be largely valued. This is my code.

```
from skopt.space import Integer, Categorical, Real
from skopt.utils import use_named_args
from skopt import gp_minimize
import tensorflow
import keras.backend as K
import GetPrediction
import Model

dim_learning_rate = Real(low=1e-4, high=1e-2, prior='log-uniform',
                         name='learning_rate')
dim_num_dense_layers = Integer(low=1, high=5, name='num_dense_layers')
dim_num_input_nodes = Integer(low=16, high=128, name='num_input_nodes')
dim_num_dense_nodes = Integer(low=8, high=64, name='num_dense_nodes')
dim_dropout = Real(low=0.01, high=2, name='dropout')
dim_activation = Categorical(categories=['relu', 'sigmoid'],
                             name='activation')
dim_batch_size = Integer(low=1, high=128, name='batch_size')
dim_adam_decay = Real(low=1e-6, high=1e-2, name="adam_decay")

dimensions = [dim_learning_rate,
              dim_num_dense_layers,
              dim_num_input_nodes,
              dim_num_dense_nodes,
              dim_dropout,
              dim_activation,
              dim_batch_size,
              dim_adam_decay
              ]
default_parameters = [1e-3, 1, 512, 13, 0.5, 'relu', 64, 1e-3]


class Optimize:
    def __init__(self, _STOCK, _INTERVAL, _TYPE):
        self.stock = _STOCK
        self.interval = _INTERVAL
        self._type = _TYPE

    @use_named_args(dimensions=dimensions)
    def fitness(self, learning_rate, num_dense_layers, num_input_nodes,
                num_dense_nodes, dropout, activation, batch_size, rms_decay):
        model = Model.Tuning_Model(learning_rate=learning_rate,
                                   num_dense_layers=num_dense_layers,
                                   num_input_nodes=num_input_nodes,
                                   num_dense_nodes=num_dense_nodes,
                                   dropout=dropout,
                                   activation=activation,
                                   rms_decay=rms_decay
                                   )

        Train_Closing, \
        Train_Volume, \
        Train_Labels, \
        Test_Closing, \
        Test_Volume, \
        Test_Labels, \
        ClosingData_scaled, \
        VolumeData_scaled = GetPrediction.Return_Data(self.stock, self.interval, self._type)

        # named blackbox becuase it represents the structure
        blackbox = model.fit(
            [
                Train_Closing,
                Train_Volume
            ],
            [
                Train_Labels
            ],
            validation_data=(
                [
                    Test_Closing,
                    Test_Volume
                ],
                [
                    Test_Labels
                ]
            ),
            epochs=250,
            batch_size=batch_size
        )
        # return the validation accuracy for the last epoch.
        accuracy = blackbox.history['val_mae'][-1]

        # Delete the Keras model with these hyper-parameters from memory.
        del model

        # Clear the Keras session, otherwise it will keep adding new
        # models to the same TensorFlow graph each time we create
        # a model with a different set of hyper-parameters.
        K.clear_session()
        tensorflow.reset_default_graph()

        # the optimizer aims for the lowest score, so we return our negative accuracy
        return -accuracy

    def Return_BestHyperParameters(self):
        gp_result = gp_minimize(func=self.fitness,
                                dimensions=dimensions,
                                n_calls=12)
        return gp_result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyClass = Optimize('DJI', '', 'Daily')
    print(MyClass.Return_BestHyperParameters())
```

Most of the code is from an article i recently read. Here is the error.

```
/home/martin/PycharmProjects/MarketPredictor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/externals/joblib/__init__.py:15: FutureWarning: sklearn.externals.joblib is deprecated in 0.21 and will be removed in 0.23. Please import this functionality directly from joblib, which can be installed with: pip install joblib. If this warning is raised when loading pickled models, you may need to re-serialize those models with scikit-learn 0.21+.
  warnings.warn(msg, category=FutureWarning)
/home/martin/PycharmProjects/MarketPredictor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/deprecation.py:144: FutureWarning: The sklearn.metrics.scorer module is  deprecated in version 0.22 and will be removed in version 0.24. The corresponding classes / functions should instead be imported from sklearn.metrics. Anything that cannot be imported from sklearn.metrics is now part of the private API.
  warnings.warn(message, FutureWarning)
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/martin/PycharmProjects/MarketPredictor/Optimizer.py", line 104, in <module>
    print(MyClass.Return_BestHyperParameters())
  File "/home/martin/PycharmProjects/MarketPredictor/Optimizer.py", line 98, in Return_BestHyperParameters
    n_calls=12)
  File "/home/martin/PycharmProjects/MarketPredictor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skopt/optimizer/gp.py", line 237, in gp_minimize
    n_jobs=n_jobs)
  File "/home/martin/PycharmProjects/MarketPredictor/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/skopt/optimizer/base.py", line 248, in base_minimize
    next_y = func(next_x)
TypeError: wrapper() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal reproducible example would be nice. But i assume that the problem is, that the function that must be minimized is a method. Therefore func inside scipy gets two arguments (self and x). 
Try this instead:

```
    def Return_BestHyperParameters(self):
        gp_result = gp_minimize(func=lambda x: self.fitness(x),
                                dimensions=dimensions,
                                n_calls=12)
        return gp_result
```

Edit to fit the decorator:

```
from skopt.space import Integer, Categorical, Real
from skopt.utils import use_named_args
from skopt import gp_minimize
import tensorflow
import keras.backend as K
import GetPrediction
import Model

dim_learning_rate = Real(low=1e-4, high=1e-2, prior='log-uniform',
                         name='learning_rate')
dim_num_dense_layers = Integer(low=1, high=5, name='num_dense_layers')
dim_num_input_nodes = Integer(low=16, high=128, name='num_input_nodes')
dim_num_dense_nodes = Integer(low=8, high=64, name='num_dense_nodes')
dim_dropout = Real(low=0.01, high=2, name='dropout')
dim_activation = Categorical(categories=['relu', 'sigmoid'],
                             name='activation')
dim_batch_size = Integer(low=1, high=128, name='batch_size')
dim_adam_decay = Real(low=1e-6, high=1e-2, name="adam_decay")

dimensions = [dim_learning_rate,
              dim_num_dense_layers,
              dim_num_input_nodes,
              dim_num_dense_nodes,
              dim_dropout,
              dim_activation,
              dim_batch_size,
              dim_adam_decay
              ]
default_parameters = [1e-3, 1, 512, 13, 0.5, 'relu', 64, 1e-3]


def fitness_wrapper(_STOCK, _INTERVALL, _TYPE):

    @use_named_args(dimensions=dimensions)
    def fitness(self, learning_rate, num_dense_layers, num_input_nodes,
                num_dense_nodes, dropout, activation, batch_size, rms_decay):
        model = Model.Tuning_Model(learning_rate=learning_rate,
                                   num_dense_layers=num_dense_layers,
                                   num_input_nodes=num_input_nodes,
                                   num_dense_nodes=num_dense_nodes,
                                   dropout=dropout,
                                   activation=activation,
                                   rms_decay=rms_decay
                                   )

        Train_Closing, \
        Train_Volume, \
        Train_Labels, \
        Test_Closing, \
        Test_Volume, \
        Test_Labels, \
        ClosingData_scaled, \
        VolumeData_scaled = GetPrediction.Return_Data(self.stock, self.interval, self._type)

        # named blackbox becuase it represents the structure
        blackbox = model.fit(
            [
                Train_Closing,
                Train_Volume
            ],
            [
                Train_Labels
            ],
            validation_data=(
                [
                    Test_Closing,
                    Test_Volume
                ],
                [
                    Test_Labels
                ]
            ),
            epochs=250,
            batch_size=batch_size
        )
        # return the validation accuracy for the last epoch.
        accuracy = blackbox.history['val_mae'][-1]

        # Delete the Keras model with these hyper-parameters from memory.
        del model

        # Clear the Keras session, otherwise it will keep adding new
        # models to the same TensorFlow graph each time we create
        # a model with a different set of hyper-parameters.
        K.clear_session()
        tensorflow.reset_default_graph()

        # the optimizer aims for the lowest score, so we return our negative accuracy
        return -accuracy

    return fitness


def Return_BestHyperParameters(_STOCK, _INTERVALL, _TYPE):
    gp_result = gp_minimize(func=fitness_wrapper(_STOCK, _INTERVALL, _TYPE),
                            dimensions=dimensions,
                            n_calls=12)
    return gp_result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Return_BestHyperParameters(_STOCK="DJI", _INTERVALL="", _TYPE="Daily"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue appears to be when `func` is called [here](https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/blob/0b610fee9f6e5760f34a3e318ec4c79499e56cc2/skopt/optimizer/base.py#L265), which effectively calls the function as `func(func.__self__, next_x)` because your function is a `bound method`. A small example that reproduce the issue would be:

```
from functools import wraps

def decorate(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(foo):
        func(foo)
    return wrapper

class Foo:
    @decorate
    def bar(self, foo):
        pass

foo = Foo()
foo.bar('foo')
```

You could use a lambda instead:

```
gp_result = gp_minimize(func=lambda params: self.fitness(params),
                        dimensions=dimensions,
                        n_calls=12)
```

Or re-organize your code so that you pass a static method instead.

Comment: Weirdly enough, I still get an error. This time it is : 

    print(MyClass.Return_BestHyperParameters())
    line 98, in Return_BestHyperParameters
    n_calls=12)
  line 237, in gp_minimize
    n_jobs=n_jobs)
  line 248, in base_minimize
    next_y = func(next_x)
  File "/home/martin/PycharmProjects/MarketPredictor/Optimizer.py", line 96, in <lambda>
    gp_result = gp_minimize(func=lambda params: self.fitness(params),
TypeError: wrapper() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: please help me sir

Comment: The `use_named_args` decorator doesn't seems to be designed to handle bound methods either: https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/blob/4b4dc6db6caacb72a9fd309b3bed57c4baf41c62/skopt/utils.py#L508

Comment: If it isn't designed for that what should I do

Comment: @MartinChtilianov See the edit in my Post. Without using a class and instead using functions. Its untested since there are some missing local dependecies, but it should work nevertheless

Comment: Thanks a lot I did something similar before your answer, without a wrapper, but thank you a lot.